# Using Asp.net MVC passing a model to build the site nav

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using Asp.net MVC create a model which can be passed to controller to build the site nav. Site nav is 4 level deep as shown below.

Html:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="/nav-url">Nav1</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/nav-url">Nav1.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/nav-url">Nav1.2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/nav-url">Nav1.3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/nav-url">Nav1.3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="/nav-url">Nav1.3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="/nav-url">Nav1.3.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/nav-url">Nav2</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/nav-url">Nav2.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/nav-url">Nav2.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/nav-url">Nav2.3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="/nav-url">Nav3</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/nav-url">Nav3.1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/nav-url">Nav3.2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/nav-url">Nav3.3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the model I created:

```
Public class Nav
{
  Public string Title
  {get; set;}
  Public string URL
  {get; set;}
  Public string Target
  {get; set;}
}
```

Now, how do I create a Object in Controller to accomplish the bind work in View. Should that be a generic List or List of List to have multiple loops to bind values to HTML ? Also, nav HTML shown above is an example and level2 or level3 can have item or may not. So my object should take care of it dynamically.

```
 List<Nav> navItems = new List<Nav>();

 List<List<Nav>> navItems = new List<List<Nav>>();
```

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: That's exceptionally lazy. In what way have you tried to solve this yourself before asking?

Comment: Sorry I was not very clear about my question earlier. I modified my question and I don't need help for the model but do need it while passing the type of object to the View, this object should help me out creating nav which is 4 level deep.

Comment: I agree with JK. 
@Kumar : Show us what you have tried. Your question almost sounds like giving an assignment to SO users.

Comment: Thanks Dark Knight for taking the time and going over my question. I'm not asking SO users to implement the logic but I'm asking for suggestion and approach to take while building the logic.

Comment: I found the work around by creating another model which will be the main object and I filled in all data as generic list and then passed that to the view.                                                                                            public class Nav
    {
        public SubNav SubNavItem
        { get; set; }
        public List<Nav> SubNavItems
        { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubNav
    {
        public string Title
        { get; set; }
        public string URL
        { get; set; }
        public string Target
        { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I found the work around by creating another model which will be the main object and I filled in all data as generic list and then passed that to the view.

```
public class Nav 
{ 
  public SubNav SubNavItem { get; set; } 
  public List<Nav> SubNavItems { get; set; } 
} 
public class SubNav 
{ 
  public string Title { get; set; } 
  public string URL { get; set; } 
  public string Target { get; set; } 
}
```